# CloseHandle on a Mutex, before ReleaseMutex - What happens?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

If I call CloseHandle on a mutex before a thread has finished with the mutex, and hence, hasn't yet called ReleaseMutex, what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: What would be the rational behind doing such a thing?

Comment: @San Jacinto:  MTA COM object has threads that are performing work and are not giving time by a caller invoking CoFreeUnusedLibraries(0, 0), with a delay of 0, which invokes DllCanUnloadNow, which returns S_OK, even though the mutex hasn't been released.  The delay for MTA is 10 minutes by default to allow threads to finish, but in this case I must check the mutex to ensure it is NULL, otherwise return S_FALSE from DllCanUnloadNow.  That stops a memory access violation we are having.  Now, the problem with waiting for the mutex to == NULL is that nothing ever explicity calls CloseHandle on it.

Comment: Wow, cool explanation. Could I suggest that you edit your question to include this information for future users?

Comment: @San Jacinto I will as soon as I get a breather ... crunch time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most serious consequence is a thread that's waiting for the mutex getting unblocked.  The WaitXxx call returns WAIT_ABANDONED.  At which point it would be a really good idea to call TerminateProcess because you have no idea what the hell just happened.

Comment: `WAIT_ABANDONED` is only reported if a thread terminates while it still owns the mutex lock.  That is different than having `CloseHandle()` called on the mutex handle prematurely.

Comment: @Remy - I think you're confuzzling the GetLastError() value you get for the ReleaseMutex() call.  I'm talking about WaitForSingleObject() and friends.

Comment: So you think WaitForSingleObject is a bad idea, to ensure the threads are finished, before calling CloseHandle?

Comment: Erm, no, using WFSO on the thread handle is the way to find out that the thread is finished.  The odds that this comment clarifies anything has to be low.

Comment: Yeah, I've just been working over 12 hours ... I'm tired.  I'll post a snippet tomorrow to show what I mean and make sure it's ok, but I think I got my answer.

Comment: @Hans - I was referring to the return value of `WaitFor...()`, not `GetLastError()`.

Comment: I think this is only true if the thread exits after failing to release the mutex.  If the thread keeps running, it presumably retains ownership of the mutex.

Answer (score 13):

`CloseHandle()` immediately destroys the handle that is passed to it. `ReleaseMutex()` will then fail with an `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` error code if called with the closed mutex handle.

If the mutex is named, there is a single reference-counted kernel object backing the mutex, but `CreateMutex()` and `OpenMutex()` return unique `HANDLE` values that have to be closed individually.  If multiple handles to the same named mutex are created/opened, calling `CloseHandle()` on one handle does not effect the other handles to the same mutex.

Answer (score 4):

CloseHandle() in this case does destroy the handle, but the mutex object is removed from memory only when all its handles have been closed.
So, by CloseHandle(handle) you will destroy that handle and so ReleaseMutex(handle) will not work. But, the mutex will still be owned by that thread with no way to release it, affecting other threads waiting for mutex lock.